# Can I assume stdio streams point to the correct file descriptor after a dup2?

Tags: c, fork, pipe, stdio, sus

I have code where I want to encapsulate a particular piece of code into a forked child so that if the code causes issues, it will not affect the parent and the parent will be able to report.

I am not `exec`ing after the `fork` call. Just plain `fork` and then the code runs that would have normally run in the parent.

The code in the child outputs stuff to `stdout` and `stderr`. Due to issues with interleaving output and `stdio` buffering, I was now looking into [TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/index.html) for a better solution.

The idea I came up with was roughly:

- `pipe()` for each stream
- `fork()`
- in child:

  - `close()` read end of pipes
  - `dup2()` the write ends onto the file descriptors for `stdout` and `stderr` respectively
  - `setbuf(fd, NULL)` to turn off `stdio` stream buffering inside the child.
- in parent:

  - `close()` write ends of pipes
  - use `select`/`pselect`/`epoll` etc (has to run across Linux, BSDs, AIX, Solaris etc) to watch the read ends of the pipes for new data and when it arrives `write()` it straight to the respective file descriptors in the parent process.

Now, I presume there is one step missing between the `dup2` and the `setbuf` inside the child. What is it?

`setbuf` takes a `FILE*` whereas of course `dup2` acts on `int`.

`freopen` came to mind, but it requires a path. If I merely want to assign a new fileno to the streams, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extern` variables `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are `FILE *` pointers. You can pass these to `setbuf` / `setvbuf`. However, note that the child has a separate address space so whilst it will inherit the state of the buffers at the time of the `fork()`, both can continue to use the buffers safely, and if you `fflush` `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, the output buffers will be empty anyway.

This is the way I would do it in the child (untested, and please do add some error handling):

```
void
child ( ... )
{
  const char *devnull = "/dev/null";

  /* turn off buffering */

  setvbuf (stdin, NULL, _IONBF);
  setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF);
  setvbuf (stderr, NULL, _IONBF);

  for (i = getdtablesize () - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if ((i != write_end_of_pipe1) && (i != write_end_of_pipe2))
        close (i);
    }

  i = open (devnull, O_RDWR);
  if (i == -1)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open /dev/null\n");
      return;
    }

  i = open (devnull, O_RDONLY);
  if (i != 0)
    {
      dup2 (i, 0);
      close (i);
    }

  dup2 (write_end_of_pipe1, 1);
  close (write_end_of_pipe1);

  dup2 (write_end_of_pipe2, 2);
  close (write_end_of_pipe2);

  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know they are `FILE*` and I even mentioned that. The question, however, remains whether after using `dup2()` to replace `STDERR_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` I'll have to reopen `stderr` and `stdout` respectively before `setbuf` or not.

Comment: No you won't. `glibc` is going to be blindly writing to / reading from FDs 0, 1 and 2. So the fact you've closed and reopened them is irrelevant. So long as the new file has the right FD and the right permissions (`O_RDONLY` or `O_WRONLY` as appropriate), you can do what you like. But obviously get it done before you need to do STDIO next.

Comment: thanks, I'll accept for now. I cannot rely merely on the behavior of glibc, though, since I have half a dozen different C runtimes to cover.

Comment: I believe it's completely standard rather than glibc specific, and I've been doing it since before `glibc` existed. Certainly older `libc` used to do it. I can't see how else stdio would work to be honest.

Comment: I guess I'll notice whenever it's not the case, so there goes the upvote. Thanks for your help.